# creating an animated search icon

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a search bar in vue. Right now the search bar opens from the left side, but I want it to open from the right side. Instead of background image, I want to use a font awesome icon as well. How do I achieve these two?

```
<template>
  <span id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</span>
</template>

<style scoped>
input {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}



input[type=search] {
    background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
    width: 55px;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
    -moz-border-radius: 10em;
    border-radius: 10em;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#demo-2 input[type=search] {
    width: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#demo-2 input[type=search]:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 130px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: auto;
}
#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for the animation but if you want to add font awesome icon you can add its link to the main template file for the vuejs . just copy paste you link to the head section in there and use the `<i>search icon</i>` in the vue code.

Answer (score 0):

### Replacing background by a font-awesome icon

You could use  `:after` or `:before` property in CSS :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before

It will allow you to display content, linked to your input (like a font-awesome glyphicon for example) :

```css
input {
   position: relative;
}
input:after {
   content: '\f002';
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 5px;
}
```

In this case, the font-awesome icon is : `\f002` :

- https://fontawesome.com/icons/search?style=solid

### Animate from the right

If you use `:after` property and the position is absolute to your input (with a `right` CSS property), it should open from the right.

Comment: it's still animating from the left side. not opening the search bar from the right. I copy pasted your exact code

Comment: @vuenewb don't copy paste code, try to make your own code using those properties. you want to put the search icon at the right don't you ?

Comment: Yes and want to expand the search input from right to left